# Custom Object Record not showing up in search

Tags: custom-object, search

I have a custom object record that is not showing up in search. I can view the record on the recent record list view, I can edit the record.

Other records of the same object show up in search.

What might be causing this particular record not to show up when searched for?

Edit - I think it might be because the record owner is a site guest user? Are records owned by guest users not indexed for search? Any way to make them searchable?

Edit2 - some records of this type created/owned by site guest user are showing in search and some aren't.

Comment: Do you have view all permission?

Comment: Yes - I have view all permission.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a record, it breaks the record content into smaller bits called as token and then indexes them. The index is sometimes slow based on the data contained in that table. It can take 15-20 minutes to index and then be available in seaches.

The record should be available in search after 15-20 mins, if that's not the case you have to raise a case with Salesforce support.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_how_search_works.htm&type=5